# “Strictness” of square brackets

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I put these definitions in a file:

```
x = 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

(It is important to define those in a file, not in GHCi, because in the latter case things become way more weird, but that’s another question.)

Now, I load this file in GHCi and:

```
λ> :sprint x
x = _
λ> :sprint y
y = _
λ> seq x ()
()
λ> seq y ()
()
λ> :sprint x
x = 'a' : _
λ> :sprint y
y = "abc"
```

What is going on here? I understand what happens in the case of `x`, that’s exactly what I expected. But what about `y`?

What I see seems to contradict [section 3.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-340003.7) of the Report, which says:

> **Translation:** The following identity holds:
>
> ```
> [e1, …, ek] = e1 : (e2 : ( … (ek : [])))
> ```

---

Furthermore:

```
y = [toUpper 'a', 'b', undefined]
```

```
λ> seq y ()
()
λ> :sprint y
y = "Ab*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
λ> :sprint y
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

---

With lists of `Char`s even actual evaluation is forced, but with other types things are still strange:

```
x = True : False : id False : []
y = [True, False, id False]
```

```
λ> seq x ()
()
λ> seq y ()
()
λ> :sprint x
x = True : _
λ> :sprint y
y = [True,False,_]
```

Comment: `:sprint` lets you look behind the scenes at the actual data structures that represent your data. There's no requirement that semantically equivalent definitions are displayed the same by `:sprint`. (In fact the whole point of `:sprint` is to change as a value becomes more evaluated, yet the value itself does not change in the process!) So there's no contradiction with the Report. But I can't say off-hand why ghci appears to build pre-constructed data for `y` but not `x`.

Comment: That said, in your `y = "Ab*** Exception: Prelude.undefined` example it seems that `:sprint` behaves poorly. It shouldn't be evaluating the elements of the string here.

Comment: @ReidBarton Yes, that’s a good point about `:sprint` and Haskell Report. And it seems that it evaluates elements only in the case `Char`s (I have added another example to the question).

Comment: You might consider filing a bug against GHCi. This seems off.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there is a special case for displaying strings in the form `"abc"` rather than `'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []` but the logic for when to do so isn't quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be just limited to `sprint`. If you write a simple program like

```
import Control.Exception

x, y :: String
x = 'a' : 'b' : undefined : []
y = ['a', 'b', undefined]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    evaluate x
    evaluate y
    putStrLn "Done"
```

then [evaluating](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) both to [WHNF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form) proceeds without touching `undefined`.

My guess is that for some strange reason GHCi decides to print `x` as a list, but `y` as a string, which is the thing that forces the evaluation of the whole `y`, not the `seq`/`evaluate` calls.

Comment: Well, looks like you are half-right. This evaluation thing happens only to lists of `Char`s, but `:sprint` with square brackets still behaves kind of strange. I’ll update my question in a moment, showing this.